# given abstract base class X, how to create another template class D<T> where T is the type of the class deriving from X?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, double-dispatch

I want to be able to accept a `Message&` object which references either a `Message1` or `Message2` class.  I want to be able to create a `MessageWithData<Message1>` or `MessageWithData<Message2>` based on the underlying type of the `Message&` object.  For example, see below:

```
class Message {};
class Message1 : public Message {};
class Message2 : public Message {};

template<typename Message1or2>
class MessageWithData : public Message1or2 { public: int x, y; }

class Handler()
{
public:
  void process(const Message& message, int x, int y)
  {
    // create object messageWithData whose type is 
    // either a MessageWithData<Message1> or a MessageWithData<Message2> 
    // based on message's type.. how do I do this?
    //
    messageWithData.dispatch(...)
  }
};
```

The messageWithData class essentially contains methods inherited from Message which allow it to be dynamically double dispatched back to the handler based on its type.  My best solution so far has been to keep the data separate from the message type, and pass it all the way through the dynamic dispatch chain, but I was hoping to come closer to the true idiom of dynamic double dispatch wherein the message type contains the variable data.

(The method I'm more or less following is from http://jogear.net/dynamic-double-dispatch-and-templates)

Comment: What is the advantage of doing it with a template rather than a virtual dispatch function since both Message1 and Message2 derive from Message?

Comment: sorry, it's not evident in the abbreviated code I posted -- `Message1` actually inherits from `Message<Message1>` which inherits from `MessageBase`.  `MessageBase` has a pure virtual `dispatch()` method, which `Message<Message1>` implements.  In `Message<Message1>::dispatch()`, a `static_cast<const Message1*>(this)` is done in order to dispatch back to the correct function in Handler.  Therefore `MessageWithData` must also be templated with `Message1` or `Message2` so dispatch() works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned, it is not possible to build your template as is.

I do not see any issue with passing additional parameters, though I would perhaps pack them into a single structure, for ease of manipulation.

Certainly I find it more idiomatic to use a supplementary `Data` parameter, rather than extending a class hierarchy to shoehorn all this into a *pattern*.

It is an anti-pattern to try to make a design fit a pattern. The proper way is to adapt the pattern so that it fits the design.

That being said...

---

There are several alternatives to your solution. Inheritance seems weird, but without the whole design at hand it may be your best bet.

It has been mentioned already that you cannot freely mix compile-time and run-time polymorphisms. I usually use Shims to circumvent the issue:

```
class Message {};
template <typename T> class MessageShim<T>: public Message {};
class Message1: public MessageShim<Message1> {};
```

The scheme is simple and allow you to benefit from the best of both worlds:

- `Message` being non-template mean that you can apply traditional OO strategies
- `MessageShim<T>` being template mean that you can apply traditional Generic Programming strategies

Once done, you should be able to get what you want, for better or worse.

Comment: Looks like MessageWithData<Message1> would need to be constructed from within a member function at MessageShim<T>'s level then, am I correct on that?  How would I tell MessageShim<T> that I need a MessageWithData<T> created as opposed to, say, a MessageWithDifferentData<T>?  I can't quite envision how the code would flow..

Comment: @Kyle: there are various possibilities, for example you could have a `virtual MessageWithData* createMessageWithData` overloaded in `MessageShim<T>` to create a `MessageWithDataShim<T>` (deriving from the former). And another overload for any other kind of data. But like I said I don't like this idea of shoving data like this much practical. Why not putting them in the visitor rather than the message if you cannot stand passing them around ?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to mix runtime and compile-time concepts, namely (runtime-)polymorphism and templates. Sorry, but that is not possible.

Templates operate on types at compile time, also called **static types**. The static type of `message` is `Message`, while its **dynamic type** might be either `Message1` or `Message2`. Templates don't know anything about dynamic types and they can't operate on them. Go with either runtime polymorphism *or* compile-time polymorphism, sometimes also called static polymorphism.

The runtime polymorphism approach is the visitor pattern, with double dispatch. Here is an example of compile-time polymorphism, using the [CRTP idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template<class TDerived>
class Message{};

class Message1 : public Message<Message1>{};
class Message2 : public Message<Message2>{};

template<class TMessage>
class MessageWithData : public TMessage { public: int x, y; };

class Handler{
public:
  template<class TMessage>
  void process(Message<TMessage> const& m, int x, int y){
    MessageWithData<TMessage> mwd;
    mwd.x = 42;
    mwd.y = 1337;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
void process(const Message& message, int x, int y)
{
  // HERE
  messageWithData.dispatch(...)
}
```

At HERE, you want to create either a `MessageWithData<Message1>` or a `MessageWithData<Message2>`, depending on whether `message` is an instance of `Message1` or `Message1`.

But you cannot do that, because the class template `MessageWithData<T>` needs to know **at compile time** what `T` should be, but that type is not available at that point in the code **until runtime** by dispatching into `message`.

Answer (score 1):

As Xeo says, you probably shouldn't do this in this particular case - better design alternatives exist.  That said, you *can* do it with RTTI, but it's generally frowned upon because your `process()` becomes a centralised maintenance point that needs to be updated as new derived classes are added.  That's easily overlooked and prone to run-time errors.

If you *must* persue this for some reason, then at least generalise the facility so a single function uses RTTI-based runtime type determination to invoke arbitrary behaviour, as in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() { }

    template <class Op>
    void for_rt_type(Op& op);
};

struct Derived1 : Base
{
    void f() { std::cout << "Derived1::f()\n"; }
};

struct Derived2 : Base
{
    void f() { std::cout << "Derived2::f()\n"; }
};

template <class Op>
void Base::for_rt_type(Op& op)
{
    if (Derived1* p = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(this))
        op(p);
    else if (Derived2* p = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(this))
        op(p);
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("unmatched dynamic type");
}

struct Op
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T* p)
    {
        p->f();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;
    Base* p1 = &d1;
    Base* p2 = &d2;
    Op op;
    p1->for_rt_type(op);
    p2->for_rt_type(op);
}
```

In the code above, you can substitute your own Op and have the same runtime-to-compiletime handover take place.  It may or may not help to think of this as a factory method in reverse :-}.

As discussed, `for_rt_type` has to be updated for each derived type: particularly painful if one team "owns" the base class and other teams write derived classes.  As with a lot of slightly hacky things, it's more practical and maintainable in support of private implementation rather than as an API feature of a low-level enterprise library.  Wanting to use this is still *typically* a sign of bad design elsewhere, but *not* always: occasionally there are algorithms (`Op`s) that benefit enormously:

- compile-time optimisations, dead code removal etc.
- derived types only need same semantics, but details can vary

  - e.g. `Derived1::value_type` is `int`, `Derived2::value_type` is `double` - allows algorithms for each to be efficient and use appropriate rounding etc..  Similarly for different container types where only a shared API is exercised.
- you can use template metaprogramming, SFINAE etc. to customise the behaviours in a derived-type specific way

Personally, I think knowledge of and ability to apply this technique (however rarely) is an important part of mastering polymorphism.

Comment: Good write-up on the part I only partly grazed with a mentioning of the vistor pattern - dynamic types and `dynamic_cast`. However, isn't that hick-hacking with `dynamic_cast` painfully slow in comparision to the visitor pattern?

Comment: @Xeo: for a single call, yes. But, if you'd otherwise need to make a many virtual calls, it can be faster to make a type determination once and then have derived-type-specific compile-time optimised code. Then as mentioned, there are some functional differences (I should be more comprehensive in listing them - will edit). Cheers.

Comment: @Tony: Good point, didn't think of batch actions. Is it possible to implement that with the visitor pattern? My brain doesn't really work right now.

Comment: @Xeo: yes absolutely... Visitor removes the ugly/unscalable if/else chain in the approach I list but requires explicit support from each derived classes (to accept the visitor and redispatch).  I'd say Visitor's more often the better choice - I just listed the above as it seemed a closer fit to the question as asked....

Comment: Sorry - rereading your first comment - you were asking for a comparison with visitor already, whereas as soon as I saw "painfully slow" my mind wandered off into thoughts of virtual dispatch and repetitive use of it without taking in that you were asking about visitor.  My "batch action" reply's not applicable to your actual question.

Comment: What's funny is the whole reason I'm doing the double dispatching in the first place is to factor out giant if-elseif-else chains, which is just what is showing up in for_rt_type